# Prolog assignment - undefined arithmetic expression error when using is/2

Tags: prolog

I have a simple Prolog program here that makes a three letter word.

```
letter(a).
letter(b).
letter(c).

word([A,B,C]).

makeword(A,B,C):-
   word([A,B,C]),
   letter(L1),
   letter(L2),
   letter(L3),
   A is L1,
   B is L2, 
   C is L3.
```

When makeword(A,B,C). is ran in the console or interpreter II am getting the error message:

> undefined arithmetic expression in A is a in module eclipse

At tracepoint:

> CALL  is_body(A, a, eclipse) @ A is L1

What is giving me this assignment error with 'is'?

I expect the output A=a, B=a, C=a

Comment: use `=` instead of `is`.

Comment: What's the purpose of `word([A,B,C])`?

Comment: You should read the documentation for `is/2`. It's for arithmetic expression evaluation. Atoms such as `a`, are not arithmetic expressions and, therefore, cannot be "evaluated". As @WillNess indicates, use `=/2`, which is the unification operator.